# Redirect non-www to www asp.net web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I have tried to non-www to www URL with pieces of code in `web.config` file But I am getting compile error

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="WWW Rewrite" enabled="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true"
                    pattern="^www\.([.a-zA-Z0-9]+)$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}"
                appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

**Compile Error:**

> Unable to start debugging on the web server. See help for common
>   configuration errors. Running the web page outside of the debugger may
>   provide further information.
>
> Make sure the server is operating correctly. Verify there are no
>   syntax errors in web.config by doing a Debug.Start Without Debugging.
>   You may also want to refer to the ASP.NET and ATL Server debugging
>   topic in the online documentation.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you have multiple `rewrite` sections in your config?

Comment: Make sure this code is located under `<system.webServer> `

Comment: That does not look like a complier error: is it actually an error from the debugger? (Normally starting the debugger with run a build, but you need to be careful to not mix up errors from build with those from the debugger.) Can you debug without this rewrite rule? Can you debug if you set the debugger's initial URL to www…?

Comment: The error is pretty clear, you have a configuration error. What does running the site outside of the debugger tell you?

Comment: I have no multiple rewrite section. @DavidG
Yes i have added in this <system.webServer> tag

Comment: without rewrite rule there have no compile error @Richard

Comment: Do you have the rewrite module installed?

Comment: No i did not installed rewrite module@DavidG

Comment: Then try installing it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure you have the [URL Rewrite module installed](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite#additionalDownloads) or it won't work and you will get errors relating to IIS not understanding the `rewrite` section in your web.config.

Comment: What if we don't have access to IIS - is it not possible to effect this solely in the Web.Config?